# Hide custom control in document outline (do not list)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to create a custom control that doesn't get listed in the document outline.

As an example i create a descendant of Button, called *MyButton*.

I drop the original Button and my descendant on the form - both get listed in the outline.

[image]

What i want to achieve is this:

[image]

*MyButton* is still on the form and in the Designer.cs file but not shown in the Document outline.

I've tried adding the [DesignTimeVisiblitity(false)] but it still shows up in the outline.

Here is what i already tried:

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
    }
}
```

Sadly none of those attributes hide the descendant in the Document Outline. I am using VS 2015.

Comment: Why on earth woud you want the outline to lie to you?

Comment: There simply isn't a way to stop the control from showing in the Document Outline. At least not with any attributes you can attach to your custom control.